# Oracle multi column derived columns update with join

Tags: oracle

I have a base table I want to update 5 values in based on COALESCED values from various other tables (derived value).  In SQL Server (tsql) I would have done something like this:

```
Update tab1
set col1 = COALESCE(tab2.val1,tab3.val1,tab4.val1),
col2 = COALESCE(tab2.val2,tab3.val3,tab4.val4),
col3 = COALESCE(tab2.val3,tab3.val3,tab4.val3)
from tab1
left outer join tab2 on tab1.joincol = tab2.joincol
left outer join tab3 on tab1.joincol = tab3.joincol
left outer join tab4 on tab1.joincol = tab4.joincol
```

I've read tons of posts on how to do this in Oracle but I can't get ANY of them to work for the above scenario!  Merge won't work because there can be multiple rows in tab1 that join and need the update from the derived values.  When I try to use "update ( select...) set" I get "ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view" even though no views are used.

Please help!  Been beating my head at this most of the day!  Not really endearing me to Oracle!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
update tab1 set
  (col1, col2, col3) = 
  (select COALESCE(tab2.val1, tab3.val1, tab4.val1),
          COALESCE(tab2.val2, tab3.val3, tab4.val4),
          COALESCE(tab2.val3, tab3.val3, tab4.val3)
   from tab2 left outer join tab1 on tab1.joincol = tab2.joincol
             left outer join tab3 on tab1.joincol = tab3.joincol
             left outer join tab4 on tab1.joincol = tab4.joincol 
  );
```

Comment: While it works syntactically, the issue with the above (as pointed out in my original question though maybe not clearly enough) is that it suffers from a "sub-query returning not exactly one row" error and therefore doesn't run.  There are multiple rows in tab1 that qualify for the updates so the join in the select produces more than one row and therefore the update fails.  I DO want ALL rows in tab1 that qualify to get the coalesced values from the other tables, thus my problem!

Comment: *Too many rows*, eh? Well, if you want to perform such an update, you'll have to get rid of it, somehow - adding a WHERE clause might help in doing that. If you could post a test case that reproduces what you really have, someone might be able to assist.

Comment: Not too many as in error.  It is completely legitimate that the particular joincol in this example is represented multiple times in the tab1 set - it's not the PK or UK value for the row.  It's also completely legitimate that every row in tab1 with a given value of joincol should receive the same updates from the coalesced values in the other tables.  Regardless of good/poor design discussions, this is what I have to work with and need to figure out how best to update.  To make it worse, it is a large data set on order of 21 million rows so it needs to perform as well!